# Styling title in a tool bar sencha touch

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I added minHeight to the toolbar as 1.5em and trying to add the title exactly at the center

```
          .checkouttoolbar .x-toolbar .x-innerhtml {
                        font-size: 15px;
                     align : center;
           }
```

but it is not working for me,Please help me on where I am doing wrong   [image]

Comment: Show us the toolbar definition please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toolbar height can be changed with the minHeight property:

```
{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    title: 'toolbar test',
    docked: 'top',
    cls: 'test',
    minHeight : '30px'
},
```

This is how you can style font-size:

```
.x-toolbar.test .x-innerhtml {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

To center vertically the title you must override line-height property on the .title element of the toolbar:

```
.x-toolbar.test .x-title {
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

Checkout the fiddle:

http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/854Wc/